# How to have PySimpleGUI default text in Output on window opening

Tags: python, user-interface, pysimplegui

I am using `PySimpleGUI` to create a text output box.

On opening the program, I would like the Output to display some default text before any button is pressed.

How can I get this to occur? `window.Read()` waits for a button press. `window.refresh()` doesn't appear to force the text to the window.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

initialString = "I want this text to display on window opening."

def gui2():
    layout = [
              [sg.Output(size=(90,20), background_color='black', text_color='white')],
              [sg.Button('Do things'), sg.Button('Exit')]
             ]
    
    window = sg.Window("Funny Title", layout)
    
    #window.read()  #I need to press a button before the text will display
    #window.refresh() #doesn't refresh the output
    print(initialString)
    #window.refresh() #doesn't refresh the output
    
    while True:
        event, values = window.read() 
        if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
            break
        elif event == 'Do things':
            print("You pressed the button")
    window.close() 
gui2()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

and of course, the answer is found 5 minutes after I post.

```py
window = sg.Window("Funny Title", layout, finalize = True)
```

This fixes the window, and the subsequent `print` statement appears in the Output as wanted.

.

Edit:
From the comment below, I've also changed the layout from sg.Outline to sg.Multiline:

```py
              sg.Multiline(size=(90,20), 
                           background_color='black', 
                           text_color='white', 
                           reroute_stdout=True, 
                           reroute_stderr=True,
                           autoscroll = True)],
```

Comment: There has been a lot of work done to the Multiline element and is now recommended for doing stdout prints.  Take a look at the call reference for the multiline and you'll find lots of controls about stdout.  You can route for example to the window AND the console, etc.

Comment: Ta a lot. I've changed it over.

Comment: I wanted to add some more details: the "finalize = True" option allows you to read from and update values of elements in the window, before entering into the main "while True" event loop. So, it allows you to put this extra code (manipulating the elements) between the "window =" declaration and the "while True" event loop.